# How do I successfully include a definition in a if function

Tags: python

How do I put a definition function into a `if` statement so when it's running the program will activate the definition by itself.

```
person=int(input("select the number of  any option which you would like to execute:"))

if (person)==(1):
    print ("please write the value for each class ")
    main()

def main ():
    juvenile=(input(" number of juveniles: "))
    adult= (input(" number of adults:"))
    senile=(input("number of seniles:"))
```

When i run it it always gives me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fenis\Desktop\TEST PAGE 4 GCSE CS CW.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Please provide your error.

Comment: Move your definition of `main()` to before the place where you're trying to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `main()` at a point where `main()` hasn't been defined. Move your definition of `main()` to above the place where you try and call it.

```
def main():
    juvenile = input("number of juveniles:")
    adult = input("number of adults:")
    senile = input("number of seniles:")

person = int(input("select the number of any option which you would like to execute:"))

if person==1:
    print ("please write the value for each class ")
    main()
```